# Page scrolling, keep the page vertical while parts of the page are horizontal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a page where the entire page is long vertically (over 3000 pixels) and some of the page can scroll to the right beyond the original page width. I had been searching for the answer awhile now and I can not seem to get it to work right.

Basically the page is set to only view with a width of 1024 pixels. At about halfway down the page I want it to scroll all a width of 4000 pixels and have a set height of 768 pixels. Once the user gets past that part the width goes back to its original 1024 pixels. In short I's like a T intersection.

I can only use HTML, CSS, javascript and jQuery.

Comment: It can't be done really. You can't change the size of the document in any direction that pleases you, whenever it pleases you. However, anything is possible, and you could make an illusion of the document being a T, by controlling the scrollbars at different levels. Have at look at other questions regarding scrolling, specifically jQuery's `on('scroll', function() { })` and the `scollTop` property. By controlling those, you could change the overflow property on different levels in the document.

Comment: I was rethinking this idea and I thought about using the iframe tag. I can make the use scroll within the the given frame. My issue is I have never used iframe before. Still new to all this and can't seem to get it to code correctly so it shows up. Thanks for the reply :) Will check back to see if anyone else has a way of doing this. I was looking a parallax scrolling as well.

Answer (score 2):

The overflow CSS property gives you the possibility to embed a scroll bar directly inside a div. You could create your page by making the content of your second section wider and using this property.

HTML :

```
<section>
    <div class="wider">
        <!--Your wider content-->
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
section{
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

.wider{
    width: 200%;
}
```

Here is a demo : http://jsfiddle.net/y42Dw/